# I am attempting to import modules automatically and execute main() in Python

Tags: python

I have a folder of modules (called modules) that currently contains 3 folders, each of which contain a package with an `__init__.py` file.
What I would like to do is iterate through the modules folder, import each of the packages and execute its `main()` function.

I have attempted to do so like this:

```
import os

for dirnames in os.walk('modules'):
    for subdirname in dirnames:
        __import__("modules", subdirname)
        func = getattr(subdirname, "main", None)
        if func:
                func()
```

but it doesn't seem to be importing the modules, let alone executing the function.

I tried adding a manual call but it returned an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 12, in <module>
    rfm_433mhz.main()
NameError: name 'rfm_433mhz' is not defined
```

EDIT:
I have added the changes as suggested but am still getting an AttributeError:

```
Module: rfm_433mhz
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 9, in <module>
    func = getattr(module, "main")
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'main'
```

For testing the `__init__.py` file has:

```
def main():
        print "hello"
```

Comment: Reread the documentation on `__import__`.  It *returns* the imported module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`__import__` returns the imported module; it does not add it to the global namespace. Also `subdirname` is still the string object, not the module. The following would work:

```
for dirname in os.list('modules'):
    if os.isdir(os.path.join('modules', dirname)):
        module = getattr(__import__("modules." + dirname), dirname)
        func = getattr(module, "main", None)
        if func:
            func()
```

I'm using `os.list()` here; `os.walk()` would *recurse* over the directories, and each iteration returns a tuple of `(dirname, directories, files)` instead:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('modules'):
    for dir in dirs:
        module = getattr(__import__("modules." + dir), dirname)
        func = getattr(module, "main", None)
        if func:
            func()
     dirs[:] = []  # don't recurse into directories.
```

Use [`importlib.import_module()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module) instead to make this easier on yourself:

```
from importlib import import_module

for dirname in os.list('modules'):
    if os.isdir(os.path.join('modules', dirname)):
        module = import_module(dirname, 'modules')
        func = getattr(module, "main", None)
        if func:
            func()
```

Comment: Further corrected; `__import__` takes a full name, not a parent and from target.

Comment: It still doesn't seem to be finding main() --
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'main'

Comment: Right, because `__import__` returns the top-level name. Further expanded.

Comment: That's the ticket. Thanks!