# p.start() blocking the rest of my loop

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm trying to run multiple main() functions from a number of modules at the same time.
I first tried using threading which worked, but I couldn't't find a way to terminate the processes when the parent process is killed nicely. so I moved onto the multiprocessing module.
However for some reason p.start() is blocking and only the first of 3 modules in the loop start.

```
import os
import signal
import sys
from multiprocessing import Process

jobs = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('modules'):
        for dir in dirs:
                print dir
                module = getattr(__import__("modules." + dir), dir)
                func = getattr(module, "main", None)
                if func:
                        p = Process(target=func)
                        jobs.append(p)
                        p.start()
                dirs[:] = []  # don't recurse into directories.

print jobs
```

Output is:

```
limitlessLED
[<Process(Process-1, started)>]
Connected to MQTT
```

Comment: don't use `os.walk` that traverses `modules` directory *recursively*. Your code: `__import__("modules." + dir)` doesn't handle it anyway. Use `os.listdir("modules")` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're destroying the contents of `dirs` **while** you're iterating over it:

```
   for dir in dirs:
            ...
            dirs[:] = []  # don't recurse into directories.
```

That's why you're only going around the loop once:  you empty `dirs` at the end of the first iteration of the loop.  Or the indentation is screwed up in the code you posted.  Hard to guess which from here ;-)

**Edit: more**

OK, looks like you copied the gist of your code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20821396/i-am-attempting-to-import-modules-automatically-and-execute-main-in-python).  You didn't copy the indentation correctly:  you indented the `dirs[:] = []` line one level too much.

Comment: ha! So I did. Still getting used to having indenting affecting program flow. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

<sub>It is posted as an answer rather than a comment, to take advantage of formatting capabilities unavailable for comments</sub>

> I'm trying to run multiple main() functions from a number of modules at the same time.

You could use `subprocess` module, to execute all `modules`' subdirectories as Python packages in parallel:

```
import sys
from glob import glob
from subprocess import Popen

processes = [Popen([sys.executable or 'python', '-m', dirname.replace('/', '.')])
             for dirname in glob('modules/*/')]
```

`Popen` doesn't block your program so all processes run at the same time. And `Popen` has `.terminate()`, `.kill()` methods that you can call any time you like, to stop the subprocesses.

It expects that packages are executable i.e., there are [`__main__.py` files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4042905/4279):

```
from . import main

main()
```